# Why the displacement current is zero outside the capacitor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electricity, maxwell-equations

Always when I study displacement
Current it is zero outside the capacitor because the electric field is zero outside

For example this photo

[image]

Why this electric field on the surface s one is zero
I wondering why is that .charges move in the circuit because of electric field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Always when I study displacement Current it is zero outside the capacitor because the electric field is zero outside

That is "mostly true". The field created by a charged capacitor is *mostly* contained between the plates of the capacitor. However there are "fringing" field lines, and a very small amount of field will go from the outside of one plate to the outside of the other.

> Why this electric field on the surface s one is zero I wondering why is that .charges move in the circuit because of electric field

The electric field through the surface s is *near* 0, but not exactly. In particular, if there is current flowing through the wire, then there is an electric field corresponding to the microscopic version of Ohm's Law.

$$\vec{J} = \sigma\vec{E}$$

Where $\vec{J}$ is the current density, $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the wire material, and $\vec{E}$ is the electric field.

Comment: The OP asks a good question, and this answer is correct.  It's not hard to show that the field in the wire is typically several orders of magnitude lower than the field in a capacitor. Why the textbooks gloss over this is a mystery.

Comment: Also i forgot to write that the electric field is zero by assuming that the wire is a perfect conductor

Comment: If the wire is a "perfect conductor" (but not a super-conductor) then the electric field internal to the _wire_ will be 0 (again using microscopic Ohm's law). But there will still be a small field outside the wire due to "fringing". It will be small, but not exactly 0.

Comment: Is there any electric field outside due to the wire

Comment: @homamhassn Yes, the wire and the plate are electrically connected, and in the electrostatic case, at equal potential. So there will be field lines perpendicular to the surface of the wire on one side, and assuming everything is symmetrical, these field lines will "loop around" the side of the capacitor and meet the other wire at a right angle as well.

Comment: so there will be electric flux on the surface that on the wire .am i right

Comment: Hold on.  The electric field in the wire (perfect conductor) is *not zero* when the capacitor is charging.  There is a field inside the wire.  It is uniform across the cross section and along the length.  This is the field that moves the electrons.  Note that in 
 the comment by @MathKeepsMeBusy where the electrostatic case is introduced has no relevance to the question.  A wire charging a capacitor is not an electrostatic situation.  Even in the electrostatic case the situation the field he or she describes is not correct.

Comment: @garyp. An ideal conductor is usually taken to mean a model of a resistive conductor as the resistivity goes to zero. (In this sense, a superconductor is not an ideal conductor.) For any uniform resistive conductor with no current, ohm's law gives a 0 electric field. Taking the limit of a zero electric field as resistivity goes to zero is still a zero electric field. Likewise, in a uniform resistive conductor, assuming ohmic linearity, for a given current density, E is proportional to resistivity. Taking the limit as resistivity approaches 0 gives E=0. You may have different idea of ideal wire

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Indeed, an ideal wire is not necessarily the same as an ideal conductor.

Comment: So why always the displacement current is zero outside (not approximation) . Notice that the displacement current is proptonal to the electric flux .and that on the perfect conductor
@garyp

Comment: In reality the displacement current outside is never zero. A perfect conductor is an idealization that does not exist.  Another way to look at it is to realize that absent resistivity in the wire the length of time needed to charge the capacitor is zero, and that the current during that "interval" is infinite.

Comment: Displacement current is not proportional to electric flux, but to the rate of change of electric flux with time. Electric flux outside a capacitor is only approximately zero. The approximation is based on model where charge is evenly distributed within capacitor plate. However charges density is different between edges and middle.